# Fundamental group, homology of the complement of the "figure eight" knot in $S^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups, knot-theory

The "figure eight" knot is the embedded circle in the three-sphere. What is the fundamental group and the homology of the complement of the knot in $S^3$?

Comment: [Related wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_group#Examples).

Comment: Look up the Wirtinger Presentation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard example in Rolfsen, which I suggest you find a copy of if you are going to look further into these kinds of questions.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=naYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=rolfsen%20wirtinger%20presentation&source=bl&ots=O_P1oZNI59&sig=fL1yjXURaxXvcYiOzPRSHoSbr4M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvvp271uTPAhVE2T4KHe6YBeMQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=rolfsen%20wirtinger%20presentation&f=false) is a link to what he says.

First, the figure 8 knot is also called $4_1$ (the first knot with 4 crossings).  On page 56 and 57 he describes the algorithm for writing down the Wirtinger Presentation of a knot diagram.  And on 58 he gives the fundamental group of Euclidean space minus the knot, $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3-4_1)$, which is the same as $\pi_1(S^3-4_1)$, which answers your first question.

Then for the homology:  It is well known the $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1$. So you will notice that when you let everything in $\pi_1(S^3-4_1)$ commute, you get just $\mathbb{Z}$. This is true for every knot.

Again, I will redirect you to [Rolfsen, page 50](https://books.google.com/books?id=naYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=rolfsen%20homology%20complement&source=bl&ots=O_P1oZQF84&sig=1RmQuBUO987_eL7BTFevwihUlqY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5o-bO4OTPAhXCQD4KHWYZDNYQ6AEIXjAJ#v=onepage&q=rolfsen%20homology%20complement&f=false) for the other homology groups.  It happen $H_*(S^3-K)$ are are all isomorphic to  $H_*(S^3-S^1)\cong H_*(S^2)$.  Intuitively, you should think about homology as not being a fine enough invariant to capture knotting.  It only sees an embedded circle as the standardly embedded unknot.